# Saving an external ID to result file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have an external data in my test data that is an id that I would like to be able to write to the the result file that is generated when I run this command:

```
./jmeter -n -t /home/usr/jmeter/script.jmx -l /home/usr/jmeter/scriptjtl
```

The id will not be used for any request, but the trackid is necessary to include i troubleshooting errors. Example of how the track_id can look: kJbc1W1YupprLcB8YZE0gla1T8APE7Td

Is there some possible away to save the track ID in the result file as a parameter or in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this `track_id` extracted into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you can use [`sample_variables` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) in order to add it to the .jtl results file, amend you command line as:

```
./jmeter -Jsample_variables=track_id -n -t /home/usr/jmeter/script.jmx -l /home/usr/jmeter/scriptjtl
```

once script finishes you will see an extra column called `track_id` containing the respective values for the `${track_id}` variable for each Sample Result

In order to make the change permanent add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sample_variables=track_id
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks as usually for your explanation of how to solve this. Following your instructions helped me solve the problem I was facing. Thank you for taking your time to write a solution, i really appreciate it!